# What is the GlobalIdentity and how do I set it in the FileNet web service?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I'm trying to upload a document into filenet via CEWS, but I'm getting this error:

> “The unexpected exception is chained to this exception. Message was: com.filenet.apiimpl.core.GlobalIdentity incompatible with com.filenet.apiimpl.core.RepositoryIdentity“

Our Filenet people don't seem to know what that means. They've provided working code that basically looks the same as mine (but which I can't compile directly at the moment because it references parts of their project I don't have.)

So is the `GlobalIdentity` something I need to pass in through the web service? If so, how? If not, where is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally spotted my mistake.

I had incorrectly set `crt.TargetSpecification.classId` to the name of the repository I was trying to use rather than to the correct classId.